# GCP: Serverless VPC connector stopped flowing data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-vpc

I have one VPC Serverless connector which helps Cloud Functions to access the default VPC and then transit to another peered VPC from another project.

The setup was working fine until yesterday.
No change happened.

Now my functions are timing out because the call to internal IPs do not return anything.

I activated the Flow logs for the VPC subnet on which the cloud functions are deployed (us-central1) and they do not show any activity at all, which points me at the Serverless VPC connector.
However it does not have any option to enable log.
I cannot try the network intelligence connectivity test since serverless infra has no IP.

I tried creating another VPC Connector with a different internal IP range, still no flow.

Any idea how I could debug this?

Comment: It's hard to believe that no change was done. If you not able to find the cause I think only [support](https://cloud.google.com/support) can help you with it.

Comment: Did you check in the activity page if nothing have changed? Especially in the firewall rule for example.

Comment: nothing in activity.... the throughput chart on the Serverless VPC connector shows 0 activity....